# How do I find the token address as on line 11 in etherscan

Tags: addresses

How do I get the token address for a token as stated on line 11? 
Got blocked out of Token.store by S.E.C. action having a U.S. IPS

I asked their support and they said the following:

If your account is with Metamask, go to https://etherscan.io/address/0x1cE7AE555139c5EF5A57CC8d814a867ee6Ee33D8#writeContract
and click "write contract"
and then use function 3 or 11 depending on if it's ETH or token

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing you can do is use a VPN. If you can't do that, then you need to edit your question detailing what you don't understand about the process that token.store support is talking about.

Comment: The guy at Token.store don't know anything about V.P.N.s. he said.  My main Q is if a V.P.N. will bypass the S.E.C. ban so I can trade on Token and DDEX. First I wanted to remove the coins but what good is that if I can't trade them. Only those two exchanges trade EMPR's How else can I get access and stay where I am at in the U.S.?

Comment: 2 said don't try. What am I supposed to do? Just loose the $$ I have in those coins? The S.E.C should allow me to trade at my own risk! Or at least allow me access to sell or remove back to my wally the coins!

Comment: Token.store can't tell you to use a VPN. If they did, they would be enabling U.S. customers trading on their platform, which would warrent the SEC possibly coming after them. You can use a VPN to trade on Token Store as long as you want. Or you can just withdraw your tokens using the VPN. You can also trade your tokens using Totle, which just launched integration with Token.store and doesn't require a VPN.

Comment: I thought they were already outside of S.E.C. influence? So what the diff they suggest I use whatever?. Thanks for the Totle info. I won't need to bother with a V.P.N. if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure where Token.store is located, but I'm assuming they're based in the US. Since the S.E.C has recently cracked down on decentralized exchanges, mainly the founder of Etherdelta, some other DEXs based in the state have been proactively blocking US customers. They suggest you use etherscan because you'd be directly interacting with their smart contracts, not their orderbook. It'd just be for withdrawing

Comment: Yes, but how do y find such an address in your wally for each coon  ticker ?